# jQuery live preventDefault failing on input elements

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I have the following snippet of code:

```
$('#messages input').live('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

where "#message input" is obviously a group of input text elements. I want to catch the "enter" key and prevent it from refreshing the page. However, it fails every time. The alert works fine, but it seems that the preventDefault() isn't working.

Anyone have any ideas?

**Edit:** I should have mentioned that I'm working in ASP.NET, and it's inside a form element. Removing it from the form element solves the problem, but I'd like to know why preventDefault() isn't working.

Comment: `alert` can do strange things to JS behavior, as it is a modal, blocking call. Try changing it to use `console.log` and see what happens. (Your code should work)

Comment: Thanks kevin, came to the same conclusion myself, and that was indeed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, it was the alert itself that was causing the problem.

AFAICT, the alert would halt the JavaScript execution before the preventDefault() could take effect, but the browser continued processing the keystroke, triggering a form submission.

Weird, but there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Might try an

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

Comment: The `e.stopPropagation()` method usually doesn't do anything for you with `.live()`. Since the event is attached to the `document`, there's really no more event bubbling to stop. Unless there's some use for it in conjunction with `e.isPropagationStopped()`? I can't imagine, though.

Comment: patrick is correct, live can't stop propagation by definition, since it's attached to the body.

Comment: Yep, didn't think about using live instead of bind.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form_deal_step1').live('submit',function(){
        $('.column .column_child select').not(':hidden').each(function(ev){
             if($(this).val()=='?')
             {
                 alert('Please select the ages of each child.');
                 ev.preventDefault();
                 return false;
             }
          });
})
var age_selected=1;
$('.column .column_child select').not(':hidden').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()=='?')
    {                
        age_selected=0; 
    }
});
if(age_selected==0)
{
    alert('Please select the ages of each child.');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: the code above var age_selected=1; is not preventing from page reload .Hence a code from var age_selected=1;
is a so different way for the same

Answer (score 0):

I think forms are submitted on `keypress`, not on `keydown`.  Try

```
$('#messages input').live('keypress', function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm aware the page refresh is a default function of the form not the input button and as such you should be preventing default on the form rather than the input.

Something along the lines of:

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
  return false;
});
```